# (Swift) Firebase keepSynced(true) does not work

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

To my Swift project I have implemented Firebase and has defined a struct for my main tableView. On my main TableView I have the values that I want to be up to date and synced with firebase. 
The firebase documentation provided these code:

`let scoresRef = Database.database().reference(withPath: "scores")
scoresRef.keepSynced(true)`
I have tried using the keepSynced function on viewDidLoad, on my fetchFunction and in AppDelegate, but apparently the values update only when I switch to another viewController and return to my mainTableView.

Below I will demonstrate my code:

My function that fetches firebase to my TableView (is included on ViewDidLoad) and Bar is my struct model:

```
    func fetchBars(){
    let myRef = ref.child("paris")
    myRef.keepSynced(true)
    myRef.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
        guard let bar = Bar.bar(from: snapshot) else {return}
        self.bars.append(bar)
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    })
}
```

Please help me with this issue and if it possible please show the examples.

Comment: What is the problem with the code you shared? What does it do? And what did you expect it to do?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen the code basically fetches all values from Firebase and displays it on table view. For example each bar with it all values assigned to the one cell. in that cell I have different kind of infos, including whether the bar is open now or closed. So I want the such infos to keep fresh.

Comment: The code you add in `myRef.observe(.childAdded` will fire straight away for each child and then whenever a child is added. Doesn't it do that?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen yes. But i also want to keep fresh the existed childs data. Any suggestion for my code?

Comment: As @FrankvanPuffelen mentioned, this code will only notify your app of .childAdded events. If you want to keep other data sync'd you would need to also include observing .childChanged and .childRemoved events. See [Working With Lists of Data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data) in the Listen for child events section. i.e. add: *myRef.observe(.childChanged*... and *myRef.observe(.childRemoved*...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had previously been stuck with this problem for a very, very long time. I almost lost hope and thought that this was legitimately a Firebase related issue.

The reason **you are retrieving cached data** rather than **the updated server data** is most probably because of the security rules you have set in the Firebase console (or the ones you haven't!). Just set the correct rules at `myRef` that allow reading from this database reference (something along the lines of `".read" = true`) and you'll be good to go!

Please note that `".read" = true` allows **anyone** to read the data at this reference. If that is not the desired behavior, then you should change the security rules at your convenience. As long as reading is allowed in your iOS app based on the rules you've set, then the `keepSynced(_:)` method will update the data rather than retrieving cached data.